# How to hide the bar on the right side of an iframe in Google chrome

Tags: css, html, iframe

I am developing an ordering food widget for a restaurant website(Please see the attached picture below). I use iframe to display menus with scroll abled. And i have hide the scroll bar in css. But it is strange that there is a bar displayed on the right hand side and I have no idea that it is. Also, this bar appears only in Windows chrome, not in Mac chrome on safari.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only Draw Back here is you have to use a Div Container outside the IFrame.

Tested in android and ios Device.

***HTML***

```
   <div class="outerCon">
    <iframe src="https://bing.com" 
            class="foo" 
            seamless="seamless">
    </iframe>
    </div>
```

***CSS***

```
.outerCon{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:500px;
    width:600px;
}

.outerCon iframe{
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit:
   overflow-x : hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.outerCon iframe::-webkit-scrollbar {
 display: none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pj7tm6ra/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To remove frame border use the below one.

```
<iframe src="myURL" width="500" height="500" frameBorder="0">Browser not compatible.</iframe>
```

Comment: Hi, Raj.In my code  I have set frameBorder = 0. I am afraid it is not the reason

Answer (score 0):

Try this [`scrolling="no"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#adef-scrolling)  or  [`seamless="seamless"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-seamless).

```
<iframe src="..." 
    class="foo" 
    scrolling="no" 
    seamless="seamless">
</iframe>
```